# Bash: Can the values of an associative array be arrays? What's its syntax?

Tags: bash, shell, arrays

I have an associative array stored in a bash file, and I'd like the values of said associative array to be arrays, but I don't even know if that's possible:

Let's say I have the file `/tmp/conf.bash`containing:

`declare -A ASSOCIATIVE=(
    ["foo"]=( "bar" "baz" )
 )`

When I tried to load it (using `source /tmp/conf.bash`) I get:

`` borrajax@wharrgarbl:~# source /tmp/conf.bash
 bash: /tmp/conf.bash: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
 bash: /tmp/conf.bash: line 2: `    ["foo"]=( "bar" "baz" )'
 bash: /tmp/conf.bash: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
 bash: /tmp/conf.bash: line 3: ` )' ``

But, if I make the file:

```
declare -A ASSOCIATIVE=(
    ["foo"]="bar baz"
 )
```

It works correctly:

```
borrajax@wharrgarbl:~# source /tmp/conf.bash
borrajax@hwharrgarbl:~# for key in "${!ASSOCIATIVE[@]}"; do \
                        echo "key: $key; values: ${ASSOCIATIVE[$key]}"; \
                        done
key: foo; values: bar baz
```

Is there a way of specifying that the values are arrays in a Bash script?

One possibility is set the values of the associative array as comma-separated strings and then split them into an array, but I thought maybe there's a way of formatting the bash file so that step is unnecessary.

I'm using Bash 4.2.28

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The values in an array (whether indexed or associative) can only be strings. It helps to think of `bash` arrays not as data structures, but a second level of quoting so that something like

```
args=("foo bar" "baz")
mycommand "${args[@]}"
```

passes two arguments, not three, to `mycommand`. In this scenario, nesting is not required, since a command can only take strings, not arrays, as arguments.